# How do you tether an iPhone with Fedora 11 over Bluetooth?

Tags: linux, iphone, tethering

I have my iPhone paired with a Fedora 11 installation over bluetooth.  When I click on the bluetooth icon on laptop and select the phone and pick connect, nothing happens.  I don't even get an error message.

What are the rest of the magic steps required to make the tethering work?  I'd imagine that this is remotely close to the same steps to make tethering work on any smartphone over bluetooth in the linux OS world.

I prefer non-jail broken solutions.  It just works for Windows Vista and 7 RC. I want to know how to make it "just work" for linux too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend Jesse Keating did and excelent guide to this, you can follow at http://jkeating.livejournal.com/75270.html

It works through bluetooth.

Comment: Could you provide a summary or the basic set of steps?  I'm saying that I don't want to click the link or anything, but having the answer here helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your iphone is jail broken I suggest trying out [PdaNet](http://www.junefabrics.com/iphone/index.php), which is a free program you can use to tether any computer to your iphone over wifi.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to tether a non-jailbroken iPhone at this time in the US is to install an unofficial carrier profile on the phone to enable tethering. While, it is not jailbroken, it is also not supported by AT&T.

Comment: Presumably, AT&T is going to offer this as an officially supported capability. Additionally, other carriers are apparently already offering it, so this question may help them if not me.

Comment: That was just a warning in case AT&T decide to lay the smack down on people with fees and such. They haven't to date, but this is At&T we're talking about.